# Capture screenshot from html page, upload to server, and use it as picture in FB feed

Tags: javascript, facebook, meteor

With my Meteor js app, my goal is to somehow capture an html page into an image then use it as the display picture in facebook feed dialog.
I did the first part of my goal using [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) script, rendering my html page into a canvas. Then I make a base64 string using the canvas returned from its onrendered method with:

```
var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
```

I wanted to save to the server and use its url in the facebook feed dialog. I tried using fs collection:
var imageStore = new FS.Store.GridFS('images');

```
Images = new FS.Collection('images', {
    stores: [imageStore]
});
```

to save the data

```
Images.insert(data, function(err, fileObj) {
    template.autorun(function(c) {
        fileObj = Images.findOne(fileObj._id);
        var url = fileObj.url();
        if (url) {
            window.open(Meteor.absoluteUrl().split('/')[0] + url);
            c.stop();
        }
    });
});
```

But the returned url is of this format:
cfs/files/images/26fFLWDvMDWuruFvt?token=eyJhdXRoVG9r...
I could open the image on the browser by just attaching the app's absolute url in front of this url but this won't work in facebook's feed dialog (deployed on the meteor's servers, my facebook dialog returns an `'Error Message: picture is not properly formatted'`).
What other options do I have to accomplish my goal? Thanks in advance

**Edit:** Sorry, false alarm :) facebook feed dialog actually can read the saved image in GridFS with

```
Meteor.absoluteUrl().substr(0, Meteor.absoluteUrl().length - 1) + url
```

Comment: How about uploading to Amazon S3 and using that URL instead?

Comment: Sorry that's a no-go for me right now. Do you know other options besides using a file storage service?

Comment: You could use something like http://cloudinary.com/